# Reconstructing integers using bit mask

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I am quite new to bit masking and bit operations. Could you please help me understanding this. I have three integers a, b, and c and I have created a new number d with below operations:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 92;

int d = (a << 14) + (b << 11) + c;
```

How do we reconstruct a, b and c using d?

Comment: Do you know which numbers reside in which bit ranges?  Given your current numerical ranges, it appears that a and b overlap (b takes up five bits, but the shift ranges only allow for 3 bits for b).

Comment: Updated the values for a, b & c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
b is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010
c is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1100

a<<14 is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000
b<<11 is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000
c     is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 1100

d     is 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0000 0101 1100
                              ^ ^      {        }
                              a b          c       



  So a = d>>14             
     b = d>>11 & 7        
     c = d>>0  & 2047     

  By the way ,you should make sure the b <= 7 and c <= 2047
```

Comment: You might want to make it clear that you are `&`ing with `7` and `2047`, and not that the results happen to be those two values.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea of the range of your `a`, `b` and `c`. However, assuming 3 bits for `a` and `b`, and 11 bits for `c` we can do:

```
a = ( d >> 14 ) & 7;
b = ( d >> 11 ) & 7;
c = ( d >>  0 ) & 2047;
```

**Update:**

The value of and-mask is computed as: `(2^NumberOfBits)-1`

Comment: 3 bits for `b` makes sense, but it looks like there are 11 bits for `c`, not 7.

Comment: Shouldn't that be 2047, not 511? (since 2^11 - 1 = 2047)

Comment: @DennisMeng: it seems i should go to sleep now :)

Comment: If we assume 3 bits per value that means the and-mask is equal to: ``(2^3)-1 = 7``.

Comment: I assume that @SergeyK. will update that if the OP ever actually says how many bits `a` actually takes.